# TLFTextField on mobile device (ios/ android )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am writing and air mobile app for android and ios and I have to use TLFTextField because I need RTL (heb).
I encounter all kind of permeable working with TLFTextField  
first event when I click the text box and set the focus the SoftKeyboard did not show up
so I had to make it show up from the code then even when the key board was open the text box didn't got the key press and stay empty.
Any idea or suggestion will be welcome?

```
    public function BaseView()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATE,onActive); 
        this.addEventListener(SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE,onDeactive);
    }
    protected function onDeactive(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void
    {
        isKeyBordOpen = false;
        trace("deactive")

    }

    protected function onActive(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void
    {
        isKeyBordOpen = true;
        trace("Active: " + event.type)
    }

    internal function addEventToTextFiled(textBox:TLFTextField):void
    {
        textBox.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,onFocus,false,0,true);
        textBox.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT,onOutFocus,false,0,true);
    }

    internal function removeEventToTextFiled(textBox:TLFTextField):void
    {
        textBox.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,onFocus);
        textBox.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT,onOutFocus);
    }


    internal function onOutFocus(event:FocusEvent):void
    {
        var txt:TLFTextField = event.currentTarget as TLFTextField;
        setText(txt,txt.text);
    }

    internal function onFocus(event:FocusEvent):void
    {
        var txt:TLFTextField = event.currentTarget as TLFTextField;

        if(isKeyBordOpen == false)
        {
            var isRisie:Boolean = txt.requestSoftKeyboard();
            trace("isRisie:Boolean " + isRisie)
            stage.focus = txt 
        }
        setBlock(txt);
    }   

    internal function setText(textBox:TLFTextField,txt:String):void
    {
        txt = StringUtil.trim(txt," ");
        textBox.needsSoftKeyboard = true;
        if(txt != null && txt.length > 0)
        {
            setBlock(textBox);
            textBox.text = txt;
        }
        else
        {
            setTrans(textBox);
        }
    }

    internal function setTrans(textBox:TLFTextField):void
    {
        textBox.background = false;
    }

    internal function setBlock(textBox:TLFTextField):void
    {
        textBox.background = true;
        textBox.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably not using this class at all but using  StageText
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html